# How do I distinguish between left and right keys (CTRL and ALT)?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, input, keyboard

I started making use of Win32's raw input features to detect all keys on the keyboard. So far, everything is working great! I can distinguish between numbers on the top row and numbers in the keypad on the right. I can even detect between the left and right shift keys. However, the control and alt keys do not return unique scan codes. The <kbd>control</kbd> key returns 29, and the <kbd>alt</kbd> key returns 56.

The popular method for checking key states on these keys is `GetAsyncKeyState`. I have tested that function using `VK_LCONTROL` and `VK_RCONTROL`, and it works, but that only helps me for capturing key down events. I would really like to be able to capture key up events as well. It is obvious that the API is somehow aware of which key is being pressed; how do I get ahold of that information?

I am currently extracting the scan code from the `RAWKEYBOARD` structure's `MakeCode` field. That gives me information about every key (and its left/right alignment) except <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd>. How would I go about capturing the key up events (and knowing whether it is left/right)? Is it possible using just the `RAWKEYBOARD` structure? Or do I have to concoct some kind of workaround?

Comment: A useful link about Windows processing input: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171535.aspx

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if you can detect key **down** events individually but only one combined key **up** event, then a simple work-around would be to keep track of whether the last key pressed down was the left- or right-key, and assume that's the same key being released during the key-up event.  Of course, this won't work if they press both keys at once; whether that's a problem depends on your use-case...

Comment: Yeah, I will definitely consider that as a viable workaround. No system will be perfect, but that would definitely be a satisfactory solution. It's just bizarre to me that win32 feeds this information to the programmer so inconsistently.

Comment: `GetAsyncKeyState` is intended to give you a snapshot of the keyboard's state. It's not intended to tell you *when* things change. That's what the `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_SYSKEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP` and `WM_SYSKEYUP` events are for. I don't see why you call this inconsistent. They're two fundamentally different things.

Comment: Reporting the shift keys and windows keys all with unique identifiers but then reporting control keys and alt keys as combined identifiers... Yes, that is quite inconsistent; you don't think so? I wasn't calling `GetAsyncKeyState` inconsistent; I was referring to the way the scan codes are passed via raw input.

Comment: Does your problem allow you to use ordinary window messages (WM_KEYDOWN WM_KEYUP etc) and examine the LPARAM? Why doesn't the left/right info in the `RAWKEYBOARD::Flags` field work for you for CTRL/ALT if it works for other keys?

Comment: Yeah, I just discovered that LPARAM in `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` contains both a scan code and an extended bit which helps determine right/left control key. However, the alt key remains elusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to get low level enough to detect key up events, you should process the WM_KEYDOWN and WM_KEYUP events:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Keystroke_Messages

> Pressing a key causes a WM_KEYDOWN or
>   WM_SYSKEYDOWN message to be placed in
>   the thread message queue attached to
>   the window that has the keyboard
>   focus. Releasing a key causes a
>   WM_KEYUP or WM_SYSKEYUP message to be
>   placed in the queue.
>
> Key-up and key-down messages typically
>   occur in pairs, but if the user holds
>   down a key long enough to start the
>   keyboard's automatic repeat feature,
>   the system generates a number of
>   WM_KEYDOWN or WM_SYSKEYDOWN messages
>   in a row. It then generates a single
>   WM_KEYUP or WM_SYSKEYUP message when
>   the user releases the key.

To distinguish between the left and right versions of the Shift, Ctrl, or Alt keys, you have to use the `MapVirtualKey()` function or the 'extended key' bit in the lParam passed with the virtual key's message.  The following function will perform that translation for you - just pass in the virtual keycode and the lParam from the message, and you'll get back the left/right specific virtual keycodes as appropriate:

```
WPARAM MapLeftRightKeys( WPARAM vk, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WPARAM new_vk = vk;
    UINT scancode = (lParam & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    int extended  = (lParam & 0x01000000) != 0;

    switch (vk) {
    case VK_SHIFT:
        new_vk = MapVirtualKey(scancode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX);
        break;
    case VK_CONTROL:
        new_vk = extended ? VK_RCONTROL : VK_LCONTROL;
        break;
    case VK_MENU:
        new_vk = extended ? VK_RMENU : VK_LMENU;
        break;
    default:
        // not a key we map from generic to left/right specialized
        //  just return it.
        new_vk = vk;
        break;    
    }

    return new_vk;
}
```

If the virtual keycode passed in isn't one that maps to a left/right version, the original keycode is passed back unchanged. So you can just run the `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP`/`WM_SYSKEYDOWN`/`WM_SYSKEYUP` message parameters through the function whenever you need to distinguish between the left and right variants.

Comment: Why is this an accepted answer? This doesn't answer the question. I know that WM_KEYDOWN exists, but how do you tell e.g. LSHIFT and RSHIFT apart in it?

Comment: @cib: You're right - I've updated the answer with details on that part of the question.

Comment: This attempt of an answer seems to be a only a hack which works in simplest cases only.  (Compare with the full answer by `DJm00n`!)  First, your code does not take into account that a scancode info is 9-bit, not 8-bit.  Second, your shortcut of “checking `extended`” works for `Type=4` keyboards (= “usual US/`ISO`/`ABNT` keyboards”), but Windows is prepared to work with about 30 types of keyboards (see `kbd.h`) — and custom layouts can deal with much more.  Your shortcut is not guaranteed to work in these cases!

Answer (score 1):

[GetAsyncKeyState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s documentation says that:

> ... If the most significant bit is
>   set, the key is down ...

which also means that if the MSB it cleared, the key is up.

Comment: This seems to be a step in the right direction, but it still leaves me unsure which key was raised up. I capture scan code 29, so I know a control key was lifted up. However, if both are now up, how do I know which one was just barely raised? I guess I need to track these keys as suggested by BlueRaja earlier.

Comment: well if you are tracking key up/down events then you must process WM_KEYUP and WM_KEYDOWN messages. parameters of these messages will tell you which key has been pressed/released.

Answer (score 1):

I have added an [example code for the official MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-message-flags):

```cpp
case WM_KEYDOWN:
case WM_KEYUP:
case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
case WM_SYSKEYUP:
{
    WORD vkCode = LOWORD(wParam);
    WORD keyFlags = HIWORD(lParam);

    WORD scanCode = LOBYTE(keyFlags);
    BOOL isExtendedKey = (keyFlags & KF_EXTENDED) == KF_EXTENDED;
    
    if (isExtendedKey)
        scanCode = MAKEWORD(scanCode, 0xE0);

    // if we want to distinguish these keys:
    switch (vkCode)
    {
    case VK_SHIFT:   // converts to VK_LSHIFT or VK_RSHIFT
    case VK_CONTROL: // converts to VK_LCONTROL or VK_RCONTROL
    case VK_MENU:    // converts to VK_LMENU or VK_RMENU
        vkCode = LOWORD(MapVirtualKeyW(scanCode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX));
        break;
    }

    // ...
}
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

To check **extended key flag** for "right" key in **lParam** also can do this way.

If true - it's right Ctrl or Alt, based on wParam == VK_CONTROL or VK_MENU

otherwise its's left Ctrl or Alt >

```
(HIWORD(lParam) & KF_EXTENDED) == KF_EXTENDED
```

To get scan code also can do this >

```
BYTE scan_code = LOBYTE(HIWORD(lParam));
```

for use

```
MapVirtualKey(scan_code, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX);
```

for detect VK_LSHIFT or VK_RSHIFT based on wParam == VK_SHIFT

Comment: This approach is defective — see my comment to `Michael Burr`’s answer.  One should use the `Dim00n`’s approach instead.