# How do you tell LSHIFT apart from RSHIFT in WM_KEYDOWN events?

Tags: c, winapi

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), `wParam` should hold the key code. The problem is, when pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>, the key code is 16 (`VK_SHIFT`), but I need to distinguish between `VK_LSHIFT` and `VK_RSHIFT`.

For `VK_CONTROL`, there seems to be a workaround:

```c
if (wParam == VK_CONTROL) {
    if (lParam & EXTENDED_KEYMASK)
        wParam = VK_RCONTROL;
    else
        wParam = VK_LCONTROL;
}
```

However, the same won't work for `VK_SHIFT`:

```c
if (wParam == VK_SHIFT) {
    if (lParam & EXTENDED_KEYMASK)
        wParam = VK_RSHIFT;
    else
        wParam = VK_LSHIFT;
}
```

In the latter example, it will just always assume LSHIFT.

Comment: It's been a while, but as far as I remember, older systems did not distinguish between left or right shift key presses.

Comment: Only `GetKeyState()` and `GetAsyncKeyState()` will distinguish between left and right key presses (from WinUser.h).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To distinguish between the left and right versions of the Shift, Ctrl, or Alt keys, you have to use the `MapVirtualKey()` function or the 'extended key' bit in the lParam passed with the virtual key's message.  The following function will perform that translation for you - just pass in the virtual keycode and the lParam from the message, and you'll get back the left/right specific virtual keycodes as appropriate:

```
WPARAM MapLeftRightKeys( WPARAM vk, LPARAM lParam)
{
    WPARAM new_vk = vk;
    UINT scancode = (lParam & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
    int extended  = (lParam & 0x01000000) != 0;

    switch (vk) {
    case VK_SHIFT:
        new_vk = MapVirtualKey(scancode, MAPVK_VSC_TO_VK_EX);
        break;
    case VK_CONTROL:
        new_vk = extended ? VK_RCONTROL : VK_LCONTROL;
        break;
    case VK_MENU:
        new_vk = extended ? VK_RMENU : VK_LMENU;
        break;
    default:
        // not a key we map from generic to left/right specialized
        //  just return it.
        new_vk = vk;
        break;    
    }

    return new_vk;
}
```

If the virtual keycode passed in isn't one that maps to a left/right version, the original keycode is passed back unchanged. So you can just run the `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP`/`WM_SYSKEYDOWN`/`WM_SYSKEYUP` message parameters through the function whenever you need to distinguish between the left and right variants.

By using `MapVirtualKey()` you don't need to know the lore about the left-shift and right-shift scancodes being 0x2a and 0x36 - the API takes care of that detail. And if they ever do happen to be different (not that that will ever really happen), Windows will be responsible for dealing with it, not you.

So in your `WM_KEYDOWN`/`WM_KEYUP`/`WM_SYSKEYDOWN`/`WM_SYSKEYUP` handlers you just have to add a line of code that looks like:

```
wparam = MapLeftRightKeys(wparam, lparam);
```

and the rest of your code can act on the left/right-specific VK codes as if the system message just gave them to you in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, kind sir! I've tested this, and it appears to work out just fine. It's also a lot cleaner and safer than the other suggestions, so I'm accepting this one. :)

Comment: This approach works in very limited set of situations only.  See [this comment of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681284/how-do-i-distinguish-between-left-and-right-keys-ctrl-and-alt#comment137833821_5681468).  Use `Dim00n`’s answer to the referenced question.

Answer (score 9):

There's ancient history behind your question.  The original IBM PC keyboard didn't have the right Alt and Ctrl keys.  They got added later on the extended keyboard layout, the keyboard controller sends them with the 0xe0 prefix to the scan code to distinguish them as extended keys.  But the original keyboard layout always had two shift keys so they have their own non-extended scan codes.  Which is why your code doesn't work.

David's answer is a good way to solve your problem.  But you actually can get it out of the message, those scan codes are cast in stone by the [Windows logo requirements](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc).  Available in lParam, the left shift key has scan code 42, the right shift key is 54.  No #define in the windows headers for them unfortunately, that makes it ugly.

Comment: Thanks for the history lesson. :)

Comment: How do you get the scancode? `unsigned char scancode = (unsigned char) (lParam >> 16);` doesn't seem to work, or gives different numbers at least. Sorry, I haven't worked with the WinAPI much.

Comment: The scan code is stored in bits 16-23, so it is (lParam & 0xff0000) >> 16.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting 42 and 54 as scancodes for lshift and rshift respectively. A quick check on the net also agrees with those numbers. Could you update your answer?

Comment: ... The more I look, the more contradicting values I get for these scancodes. Are you sure they're "cast in stone"?

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you, sir. That explains the mess with scan codes and the multitude of window messages and their bits and parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Call [`GetKeyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx) passing `VK_LSHIFT` or `VK_RSHIFT`.

Comment: Good idea, I'd obviously prefer something like the "hack" in my example, but if there's nothing like that, this'd definitely work.

Comment: This is a very clean way to do it. Using the synchronous key state API.

Comment: It's clean as long as we can assume that key states are always updated before the WM_KEYDOWN message is dispatched. I wasn't sure about that before, but you seem to be right, from what I can read further down in the GetKeyState docs.

Comment: Actually, I just thought of a problem: If you're holding down the other shift key at the same time, there'd be no way to tell which of them was just pressed. Not that it's likely to come up, but the issue exists.

Comment: @cib: What do you mean?  If both shift keys are down, `GetKeyState` can tell you that are both were down.  Or are you trying to determine in which order both Shift keys were pressed?

Comment: Well, say the left shift is being held, and somebody presses the right one. Now I won't know if the left or the right one was pressed using this method.

Comment: @cib But in that situation, both are pressed, and `GetKeyState` will tell you that.  What result do you want instead?

Comment: @jamesdlin He wants to know which one cause the WM_KEYDOWN message that is currently being processed. Hans has the answer.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I want to know the button that triggered the event. That's why WM_KEYDOWN is used, instead of GetKeyState(). Basically I'm trying to adapt the windows KEYDOWN event to a cross-platform API which treats LSHIFT and RSHIFT as separate buttons.

Answer (score 1):

"According to MSDN":

> - VK_LSHIFT
> - VK_RSHIFT
> - VK_LCONTROL
> - VK_RCONTROL
> - VK_LMENU
> - VK_RMENU
>
> These left- and right-distinguishing constants are available to an application only through the GetKeyboardState, SetKeyboardState, GetAsyncKeyState, GetKeyState, and MapVirtualKey functions.