# How to press Right Shift key in Java robot?

Tags: java, keypress, awtrobot

Can you help me refactor this code:

```
public static void pressRightShift() {
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
}
```

Please mention how to press for right\left shift keys as well.Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you tell LSHIFT apart from RSHIFT in WM\_KEYDOWN events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15966642/how-do-you-tell-lshift-apart-from-rshift-in-wm-keydown-events)

Answer (score -1):

I found a Java tutorial that includes a Java WebStart sample and the source code. Looks like the winner is KeyEvent.getKeyLocation()

```
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_LEFT
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD
KeyEvent.KEY_LOCATION_UNKNOWN
```

References:

[KeyEvent Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)

[Key Listener Demo and Source Code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but KeyEvent.getKeyLocation() allows you to determine which of the Shift was pressed. 
But I still don’t understand how to click on the right shift use robot.keyPress