# How to tell which Alt key was pressed

Tags: c++, linux, qt, input, keyboard

I need to write a GNU/Linux program (C/C++) in which I can get an information which (left or right) <kbd>Alt</kbd> key was pressed.

**QTKeyEvent** will not work and **linux/input.h** library seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut. Is there other solution?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5681284/how-do-i-distinguish-between-left-and-right-keys-ctrl-and-alt

Comment: Did you look at QKeyEvent::nativeScanCode()? My keyboard don't have a right ALT key (just AltGr)

Answer (score 0):

Actually in most keyboards, the right alt key is altgr.

```
Qt::Key_Alt
Qt::Key_AltGr
```

Edit: Sorry I can't leave a comment, I need 50 rep for that.